# Java MongoDB pretend to be replication slave

Tags: java, mongodb, replication

What we're trying to do is what Meteor is doing with Mongo with LiveQuery, which is this:

> Livequery can connect to the database, pretend to be a replication
>   slave, and consume the replication log. Most databases support some
>   form of replication so this is a widely applicable approach. This is
>   the strategy that Livequery prefers with MongoDB, since MongoDB does
>   not have triggers.

[Source of that quote here](https://www.meteor.com/livequery)

So is there a way with **com.mongodb.*;** in Java to create such replication slave so that it receives any notifications for each update that happens on the primary Mongo server?

Also, I don't see any replication log in the **local** database. Is there a way to turn them on?

If it's not possible to do it in Java, is it possible to create such solution in other languages (*C++ or Node.js maybe*)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start your database with the `--replSet rsName` option, and then run `rs.initiate()`. After that you will see a rs.oplog collection in the local database.

What you are describing is commonly referred to as "tailing the oplog", which is based on using a [Tailable Cursor](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-tailable-cursor/) on a capped collection (the MongoDB oplog in this case). The mechanics are relatively simple, there are numerous oplog tailing examples out there written in Java, here are a few:

- [Event Streaming with MongoDB](http://www.warski.org/blog/2012/11/event-streaming-with-mongodb/)
- [TailableCursorExample](https://github.com/deftlabs/mongodb-examples/blob/master/mongo-java-tailable-cursor-example/src/main/com/deftlabs/examples/mongo/TailableCursorExample.java)
- [Wordnik mongo-admin-utils](https://github.com/wordnik/wordnik-oss/blob/master/modules/mongo-admin-utils/README.md#comwordniksystemmongodbincrementalbackuputil)
- [IncrementalBackupUtil](https://github.com/wordnik/wordnik-oss/blob/master/modules/mongo-admin-utils/src/main/java/com/wordnik/system/mongodb/IncrementalBackupUtil.java)

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, I will look into that!

Comment: And then, using the "ts" field in the oplog.rs collection, I managed to keep track of the last changes. Thanks again for your answer.